# icmpping in Zabbix, one item multiple server

Tags: icmp, zabbix

I want to check availability of 16 machines with a single simple check item in zabbix, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible - it's not how Zabbix operates. You must have an item per host.

What you can do, is template that item. That allows you to configure it once, then apply that configuration to all your hosts. See [the official manual on templates](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/templates).

Comment: I thought maybe macros can help

Comment: Macros would allow to customise items per host, but they wouldn't really help with multiplying that configuration.